# GCP JSON API:How to give bucket editor permission to all authenticated users [to create & edit their own private bucket(s)]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-apis-explorer

I am developing a webapp where users login via oAuth.
How can I allow users to create their own private buckets, so that they can create & update objects within their respective private buckets?

Currently, it shows error 403 when using list buckets API.
Authentication is working well as it shows response 200 on authentication. (using token & API key)

Thanks :)

Comment: This is a bad idea. All authenticated users mean anyone with a Google Account. I would be able to create a bucket, store vast amounts of information and you will pay the bill.

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation, there are the [Intrinsic permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#primitive-roles-intrinsic), that you can check to verify which of the permissions need to be provided to users to be able to create buckets for their own.

For a user to be able to create buckets, they need to have at least the privileges of an **Editor**. The permissions needed are the following:

```
storage.buckets.create
storage.buckets.delete
storage.buckets.list
storage.hmacKeys.*
```

I would recommend you to check the documentation and give it a try, checking this documentation and to check the following article, with more information as well.

- [Overview of Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control)

For you to add the permission automatically, once the users are created/signed up, you will need to program your application to add specific roles for the user that just signed up.

More information on how to achieve this automatically addition of permissions, can be found in the below documentation.

- [Cloud IAM policy](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#cloud-iam-policy)
- [Granting a role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting-role)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But how do I grant this permission to all authenticated users? (I do not have a predefined email list & authenticated users will be added dynamically)

Comment: Hi @dhanursehgal I have updated my answer with the information on where you can check on how to add automatically the permission on new signed up users.

Comment: So we need a 2nd server for the sole purpose of detecting new signups & granting roles/permissions? (because user won't be able to call  projects.setIamPolicy)

Comment: Hi @dhanursehgal once your application has the functions to allow signup, you can configure this other function of adding the permissions as well, so, you won't need specifically a new server just for this.

Comment: I see that SetIAMpolicy doesn't allow allAuthenticatedUsers to be included. I tried using the cmd console as well.

Comment: Hi @dhanursehgal indeed. You will need to create functions via code that will authorize you to do that. I recommend you to take a look at the last two articles from my answer, to get more details on how to achieve the granting.